# JsonWebsocketConsumer class self.send() in a loop sends all the iterations messages at once

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

when I use self.send(content) in a loop , all the messages are sent at once , instead of one my one.

the first self.send() in the if condition od connecting is executed perfectly 
but all loop self.send() messages are recieved by client at once after a delay of about 60 second. how to make it one at a time?

```
consumer.py
from channels.generic.websockets import JsonWebsocketConsumer

class MyConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    # Set to True if you want it, else leave it out
    strict_ordering = False
    def connect(self, message, **kwargs):
        super(MyConsumer,self).connect(message)
        pass
    def receive(self, content, **kwargs):
        if content['status'] == "connecting":
            content['status'] = "connected"
            self.send(content)
        elif content['status'] == "data":
            for p in range(5):
                content={
                    'status': 'sending',
                    'polygon': p
                }
                self.send(content)
                time.sleep(15)
            self.close()
    def disconnect(self, message, **kwargs):
        pass
```

clientside.js

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/mahaplans/");
                    socket.onopen = function () {
                        var msg = {
                            status: "connecting"
                        };
                        socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg))
                    }
                    socket.onmessage = function (e) {

                        let status=JSON.parse(e.data)

                        if (status["status"]=="connected") {
                            var imageData={
                                #someddata
                            }
                            socket.send(JSON.stringify(imageData))
                        }

                        if (status["status"]=="sending") {
                            console.log(status["polygon"])
                        }
                    }
                    socket.onclose = function (event) {
                        console.log("bye bye")
                    }
                if (socket.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) socket.onopen();
```

Comment: I suggest using the `AsyncWebsocketConsumer ` then you can `await` the `send` and `await the async .`await asyncio.sleep(1)`. In the sync consumer the consumer might not be able to process your `send` events until the `receive` method has completed.

Comment: @MatthausWoolard I am using Django Channel 1.8 so I cant use AsyncWebsocketConsumer. Is there any other alternative solution to the problem?

Comment: Channels before v2 had a very different runtime model I'm not very familiar I'm afraid. Is there something stopping you upgrading to v2?

Comment: yes. I can't upgrade to v2 because of some reasons. Thank you for telling me the reason i.e the receive Function completion. I solved the problem by changing the logic and using an if instead of for and sending a message back for each iteration so that the receive function is completed each time.